Does google knowledge graph show family members
I want to get the family members of Angela Merkel from the knowledge graph api. However, the data doesn't seem to exist even though it exists in the google panels which are apparently powered by the knowledge graph. I do the following query in the API
import json
import urllib

API_KEY = "12345"
query = 'Angela Merkel'
service_url = 'https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search'
params = {
    'query': query,
    'types': 'Person',
    'limit': 10,
    'indent': True,
    'key': API_KEY,
}
url = service_url + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
response = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
response['itemListElement'][0]

And I get the following results:
{'resultScore': 749.7,
 '@type': 'EntitySearchResult',
 'result': {'description': 'Former Chancellor of Germany',
  '@id': 'kg:/m/0jl0g',
  '@type': ['Person', 'Thing'],
  'image': {'url': 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Angela_Merkel._Tallinn_Digital_Summit.jpg',
   'contentUrl': 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhKsL6H7E2xkluj36X8GTbnVRAGdWcFg2CskmkpSEYGY8YLgbd'},
  'name': 'Angela Merkel',
  'url': 'http://www.angela-merkel.de/'}}

Note the family members do not exist
